# How to log android with network user's credential?

Tags: c#, android, windows, xamarin.forms

I am trying to save files to the shared folders on the network. These androids do not have sim cards. The problem I have is a permission denied to write in the folder. But I do not know how to add devices to the shared network. How should I go about givin permission to these devices?

Can I create a single user for all of them and use it? Or do I have to create a separate user for each devices?

In the possibility it's my code that's wrong, I'll post the relevant part. Note that I can confirm I am connected to the network.

```
string basePath = @"\\Nascld\Share\DeliveriesPictures";
Directory.CreateDirectory(basePath);
string path = $@"\{piece}.jpg";
File.WriteAllBytes(path, image);
```

piece is a decimal and image is a byte[].
Whenever i try to access the folder, I get a "read only" folder, but it's not readonly. I belive it's a lack of permission.

Thank you for the help and have a nice day

Comment: Use Window File Explorer to change permissions if you are the owner.

Comment: @jdweng My problem is that I don't know how to change the permission given to the device. I have access to the folder, but I cannot just say "anyone connected to the network can access it". The device is not registered as a user in the active directory to give him permissions. How can I add a device to the active directory?

Comment: With Explorer right click folder :  Security Advance : Share : Type :allow, Principal EveryOne, Access : Full Control.  Then apply to all subfolders.

Comment: @jdweng that would give everyone full access to the files. I'm not trying to give everyone access, I'm trying to give each of these devices.

Comment: Is android connected to your windows network? You have to first add android into network so windows recognizes the credentials.  The you do not need to use credentials with username and password since device is already connected.  Then you just need to add the android to the shared access instead of using EveryOne.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using sharpcif.

```
try
{
    SharpCifs.Config.SetProperty("jcifs.smb.client.lport", "8080");

    //Get Auth
    var auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication("Domain", "username", "Password");

    //Make path Name
    string path = $"smb://Nascld/Share/DeliveriesPictures/{piece}.jpg";

    //Get target's SmbFile.
    var file = new SmbFile(path, auth);

    //Create new file
    file.CreateNewFile();

    //Get writable stream.
    var writeStream = file.GetOutputStream();

    //Write bytes.
    writeStream.Write(image);

    //Create reading buffer.
    var memStream = new MemoryStream();

    //Dispose writable stream.
    writeStream.Dispose();

    IDeliveryService client = Common.GetDeliveryService();
    //client.TransformEqual(_callContext, piece, journalSrc, type, id, journalDest);
}
```

and it worked